# solidworks pdm api file modified date

Tags: .net, vb.net, solidworks, solidworksapi

There is a method to get file modified date of an archived file?

This code only works if the file is present in the local folder

```
    Dim vPath As String = "C:\Vault-Ats16\Dis03\0300\0312_L3078 Cid - Att_ra Per Rilievo Vibrazioni\03120100 Attrezzatura di Collaudo"
    Dim vFilePath As String = vPath + "\" + "03120101 Piastra Base.SLDPRT"

    Dim mVault As IEdmVault18 
    mVault = New EdmVault5`

    Dim vFo As IEdmFolder5 = mVault.GetFolderFromPath(vPath)

    Dim vFi As IEdmFile8
    vFi = mVault.GetFileFromPath(vFilePath, vFo)

    Debug.Print("Data File      :  " + DirectCast(vFi.GetLocalFileDate(vFilePath), DateTime).ToString)
```

I do not find how to get the same result if the file is not present in the local folder

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a method to get the modified date of a file unless the file is locally cached. PDM doesn't know if a file that is checked out elsewhere has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need the file to be locally cached because the last saved (modified) datetime is a metadatum saved within the file itself. I have found [this](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/swdocmgrapi/SolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr~SolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr.ISwDMDocument19~LastSavedDate2.html) to be the most accurate way of getting the last saved datetime. Returned time is in unix format.